# Ordenar datos en python

Tags: python, numpy

No se como ordenar los datos en python

tengo la siguiente estructura

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [...]
  ...
]
```

me gustaria ordenarlos para imprimir en una tabla,
algo como:

```
Tiempo | Precio | Volumen
1      | 2      | 3
...    | ...    | ...
```

Y si quiero tener los datos de tiempo usar algo como `datos[Tiempo]`. Creo que con numpy se puede pero no estoy seguro como

Comment: Se puede usar pandas?

Comment: Si, estoy investigando un poco.. pero ya tengo 2 horas aquí tratando de dat con solucion.

Comment: Para manejar los datos de esa forma como lo planteas (datos[Tiempo]) sin necesidad de librerias externas creo que es mejor convertirlos a un diccionario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok la solución es fácil, al utilizar pandas podemos crear un dataframe usando listas solo necesitamos especificar la data y las columnas

```py
import pandas as pd

#definimis las columnas
cols = ["tiempo","precio","volumen"]

#definimos la data 
data =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

#creamos nuestro df
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
```

Ahora si podemos acceder a cualquier columnas con  `df["tiempo"]`

Lo mejor es obtener los resultados y convertirlos a una lista, solo si los quieres ver mejor y manejar los de otra forma

```py
print(df["tiempo"].tolist())
```

**Resultado**

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Claro que con numpy también se puede, lo único que para una mejor visualización de los datos usaré además de la biblioteca numpy, tabulate

#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

datos=[
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]]

l=np.array(datos)
```

importamos las bibliotecas y convertimos la lista a una matriz(array)

```
print(tabulate(l,headers = ["Tiempo","Precio","Volumen"],numalign='center',tablefmt='grid'))
```

con esto mostramos la matriz con un formato y cabecera especificados

```
tiempo = l[...,0] #se conserva como array, es un simple slice
```

definimos el array de tiempo y solo queda mostrarlos.

```
print(f"Valores de tiempo : {tiempo}")
```

Resultado:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|  Tiempo  |  Precio  |  Volumen  |
+==========+==========+===========+
|    1     |    2     |     3     |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|    4     |    5     |     6     |
+----------+----------+-----------+
Valores de tiempo : [1 4]
```

hay más opciones para tabulate pero están en la red, además trae el modificador -h (help) que puede ayudarte